# Android app for maps doesnt work on another device

Tags: android, maps, device

I was using the apk on my phone and it works fine. Now when I installed the apk in another phone, the maps don't show up. What is wrong here?

Comment: What are the 2 phones?  What are the Android versions on those phones?

Comment: Xperia Z (mine) 

LG Optimus F160 (Friend's)

Both using the same version of android. i.e. Jellybeans

Comment: How did you created the API key?? I mean the key of which keystore file is used??

Answer (score 1):

Map is related to `SHA fingerprint`. If you create key with `debugkey` store then it will run only when you install it from a PC. So to run it on very device, create one `keystore` and register its SHA fingerprint for Map online and export apk

Comment: I tried to run it through my PC, but the other device won't start up the app. It doesn't get installed on the device through my PC so I had to copy the .apk from pc to device

Comment: I think you are using debugKeystore by default. which map you are using Google map V2 or normal

Comment: How do I use the Release keystore? And from where can I get it?

Comment: you to make it while exporting application and then register SHA at google console project http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-maps-android-api-v2-mapfragment.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, the declaration of the API key in the android manifest.xml is

```
`<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />`
```

the string value of @string/google_maps_key for the debug mode and release mode are found in different folders. check src/release and src/debug if they both have the API key

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and finally it is solved!
fingerprint is used to restrict usage to your Android apps 
go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and delete Sha1 fingerprint and now anyone can use your app